# Get timer time from UIDatePicker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidatepicker

How do you get the time entered from a UIDatePicker?

I have a button to press, and I have an IBAction, so what code would get you the data?

I would also like the time entered on the timer, instead of starting a timer.

Oh yeah, and the Date Picker is a timer, not a date.

Answer (score 10):

You have a UIDatePicker with datePickerMode set to UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer?

To get the currently selected value, use:

```
NSTimeInterval duration = datePickerView.countDownDuration;
int hours = (int)(duration/3600.0f);
int minutes = ((int)duration - (hours * 3600))/60;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let t = datePicker.countDownDuration
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: t)
let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
var components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: date)
var hour = components.hour
var minute = components.minute
return String(format: "%02d:%02d", hour, minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help? 
[UIDatePicker as timer](http://vimeo.com/5284584)(video on vimeo)

Comment: Thanks, but I would like the time entered on the timer, instead of starting a timer.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the above code snippets, by using NSDate will result in todays date & the current time...

NSDate *dmd = [NSDate date];

```
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dmd];
        NSArray *temp=[dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
        NSLog(@"%@",[temp objectAtIndex:1]);
```